# which database is suitable for react native app?

Tags: database, react-native

I am planning to build a react native application, where at some point i should use a database, which database is suitable for online react native and how will i connect db with my react native code?

Answer (score 1):

Databases should be linked to the server, and not directly to the app for obvious security purposes. An App is just like the front-end part of a website: if it's executed in client-side, it's not safe.

So any back-end framework with a SQL DataBase will do (PHP frameworks like Symfony or Laravel or NodeJS) You will have to get your data with react native's `Linking` fetch API, by adding a token if you want to limit the access to connected users only.

But good news, if you're not very comfortable setting up a server, you could always choose a server-less solution like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) .

I definitely recommend it. You could save a lot of time and end up with a very secure and fast solution to manage your app's data. Just be aware that only a limited number of requests per day are free (but don't worry, it's not that expensive and it gets paying only with a great number of request per day). You will have to learn how to use it by reading the docs though, it might take you a couple of days, but trust me it's not rocket science.

(Disclaimer: I'm not advertising for Firebase, I just enjoyed using it so I recommend it)